# How to Detect changed data immediately in angular web page

Tags: angular, ngzone

This is my angular html code.

```
 <tr *ngFor="let asset of myRequestResumeList">


            <td class="asset-properties">{{asset.userId}}</td>

            <td class="asset-properties">{{asset.requestDetails}}</td>

            <td class="asset-properties">{{asset.requestResumeAssetId}}</td>
            <td>
              <form>

                <div>
                  <button (click)="updateAuthentication(asset.userId, asset.requestDetails, asset.requestResumeAssetId, '인증' );" type="submit">승인</button>
                  <button (click)="revokeRequestUser(asset.requestResumeAssetId);" type="submit">거부</button>
                </div>
              </form>
            </td>


          </tr>
```

when button(updateAuthentication) is clicked,
asset matched asset.userId is deleted from myRequestResumeList.

updateAuthentication function is completed.

but deleted asset is Remain in angular page.

I want to see changed page without webrowser refresh button.

I study about ChangeData(Ng zone)
but It's to hard to me.
I don't know how to apply Ng zone to my code.

please give me advice(easy way) to see changed page immediately

Comment: paste you .ts code also.

Comment: are you using `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`?

Answer (score 0):

Add `*ngIf="asset.userId"`

`<td class="asset-properties" *ngIf="asset.userId">{{asset.userId}}</td>`

But adding `ngIf` on `td` will break your table , so use a `span` inside `td` , like `<td><span *ngIf="asset.userId">
{{asset.userId}}</span></td>`

**EDIT**

The problem was that OP was not receiving the updated object in response from the server, so that resulted in view not getting updated.

Comment: I try to your advice.
but, page is not changed. 
only webBrowser refresh button provide changed page.

Comment: @abc How you are changing your object? I mean how do delete asset.userId? Try console log  after you do that and see if that is actually being deleted from object

Comment: thank you, 

after recheck, when button is clicked, rest-server's data is changed.
but I do not receive  again myRequestResumeList from rest-server

Comment: @abc So everything will work as expected on client when you send updated object in the response from server?